# Overriding renderfield.php in contact form

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-3.6

I've got trouble with my contact form.
It seems that **com_contact** is using its own `renderfield.php` that can be found in `components/com_contact/layouts/joomla/form`.

1. Why its own `renderfield.php` and not its own `renderlabel.php`?
2. How do I override `renderfield.php`?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the function `getRenderer` in `libraries/joomla/form/field.php` is the one returning the rendering path, and the bug is there. I haven't tested this, but a quick search in the filesystem points me to that function.

In any case, you don't need, in my opinion, to go through the hassle and override the renderfield.php. You can just override the `default_form.php` ( `com_contact/views/contact/tmpl/defaut_form.php` ) and replace the following line:

```
<?php echo $field->renderField(); ?>
```

with a call to your function

```
<?php echo myRenderField($field); ?>
```

Where `myRenderField` will render `$field` in the way that you want.